# How to get Average speed, Total Duration from CMPedometer?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

How to get **Average speed**, **Total Duration** from `CMPedometer`?

`CMPedometerData` is only returning number of steps and distance.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't available natively via CMPedometer.

And the reason for this is that a regular human being does a combination of sitting down, standing up, walking, and a number of other things all at the same time.

So what you really want to do is call [`queryPedometerDataFromDate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMPedometer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CMPedometer/queryPedometerDataFromDate:toDate:withHandler:) (which you can call immediately or periodically after calling [`startPedometerUpdatesFromDate:withHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMPedometer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CMPedometer/startPedometerUpdatesFromDate:withHandler:) -- perhaps when your user clicks a "Start Pedometer" button, or some specific time interval that you schedule throughout the day).

Using either that query, or the handler, you can come up with both the total time for your user's current walk or jog ([`endDate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMPedometerData_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMPedometerData/endDate) - `startDate`) and the average speed (the distance divided by the time duration for that CFPedometerData entry).